# Poems About Ungratefulness

Tags: word-requests

Looking for poems about ungratefulness.

Found some recommendations on 百度知道 under the question: [关于自己忘恩负义的诗词](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/536331948.html?device=mobile&ssid=0&from=844b&uid=0&pu=usm@0,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_8.1_3_600&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=B0DC14BD4CFD809A8478494C15B38C6D&tj=www_normal_1_0_10_title); especially the poem《氓》- wondering what else is out there.

- What poems are there about ungratefulness?

Comment: ctext.org might be useful - can search in 全唐詩 for phrases like "忘恩"?  Or are you asking about bits of poems that achieved 成語 status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one about forgetting the help which you once relied on to succeed. More readings: [教育百科](http://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E5%BE%97%E9%AD%9A%E5%BF%98%E7%AD%8C) [奇摩知識](https://tw.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/question?qid=1510090107723)

> 筌者所以在魚，得魚而忘筌；蹄者所以在兔，得兔而忘蹄；言者所以在意，得意而忘言。
>   《莊子·外物》

If you are interested in fable prose as well, 《中山狼傳》is a pretty good one. As a matter of fact, 《紅樓夢》once quotes 《中山狼傳》to describe ungratefulness. More readings: [詩詞網](http://www.shiciwang.org/18752.html) [百度百科](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1282198.htm) [互動百科](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E3%80%8A%E4%B8%AD%E5%B1%B1%E7%8B%BC%E4%BC%A0%E3%80%8B) [奇摩知識](https://tw.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/question?qid=1005040908753)

> 子系中山狼，得志便猖狂。金閨花柳質，一載赴黃粱。《紅樓夢》

Comment: i've never seen that first quote be used in reference to ungratefulness - i thought it was a philosophical meditation concerning the relationship between words and ideas (i.e., words are mere tools to convey ideas ; these words can be discarded/forgotten once they've served their purpose).  Can you provide an example of use where it implies "ungratefulness"?

Comment: You are right, the very original meaning is not about ungratefulness. But the phrase 得魚忘筌 which is from this quote now mostly refer to ungratefulness. See the 教育部成語典 http://dict.idioms.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cydic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=uwKnZg&o=e0&sec=sec1&op=v&view=0-1&fmt=11 "亦用來比喻人在達到目的成功後就忘掉賴以成功的手段或憑藉物，有背義忘恩之意。"

Comment: I had no idea it could be used that way!  Thank you for the clarification.